# Pause an event on click or touch, then "restart" state event after doing some work in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking to implement a way to track clicks specifically - if there's a better way to do this, but I would really like to know how to simply delay all the same event propagation that happens normally until some function has been finished up - thoughts?

```
$(this).on('click touch', function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     l("clicked ");

     setTimeout(function(){
         l('redispatching event');
         event.target.parentNode.dispatchEvent(event); // fails here?
     }, 500);

     return false;
});
```

Edit was for a more specific example.

Answer (score 2):

Use `event.preventDefault()` like normal, then when you want to bubble up, dispatch the same event directly to the element's parent.

```
$('a, button').on('click touch', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.cancelBubble = true;
        doSomething(); // Probably asynchronous
        event.cancelBubble = false;
        event.target.parentNode.dispatchEvent(event);
        return false;
})
```

Comment: hum don't you forget the `event` in `function(event) { ...` ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work `Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'.`

Comment: @SimonDehaut Whoops, don't know how I missed that! Thanks!

Comment: @RossTheBoss Yep, as Simon pointed out, I forgot to bind the parameter in the callback. I just edited that in now; it should work now.

Comment: Still fails actually ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
Take a look at my edited example above if you have any thoughts?

Comment: Ah, looks like preventDefault doesn't stop the bubbling. For that, you need to set cancelBubble to true. I've edited the code above to match; I've tested it with vanilla JS and it works, so it should work with jQuery as well.